# Status Update Form Component not giving access to camera roll

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I am trying to implement the status update form component in my react native project.  The component is giving me an error in reference to the expo permissions API, saying the package has moved.  On my end, I have made sure to update all of my expo related packages and dependencies, as well as installed permissions and imported it correctly.

In the react-native activity feed example app provided by Stream, the status update form only allows you to post an activity with just text and hashtag, but no image.  Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on?